# Windows-specific .NET code under Mono

Tags: .net, mono

What if I have a .NET library which has WinApi calls (ADO.NET, for example), and I want to use it under Mono? I guess it (Mono application) won't work under Linux, but will it work under Windows?

Just curious.

Comment: If an assembly has Windows specific code, then it's highly likely to work on Windows. :)

Comment: Is it that the library written by someone else that youlre planning to use has WinApi calls in it, or are you planning to write your own library that will have those calls in it?

Comment: If you plan on writing your own library with WINAPI calls in it, you probably need to do it using Microsoft's tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono offers an [ADO.NET Provider Factory.](http://www.mono-project.com/ADO.NET)

You are correct that, if you have an external library that uses WINAPI calls, it should work, but only if you are on a Windows platform.

Comment: It should.  The Mono runtime will call your external library, and at that point you will be inside your library code, running on a Windows platform, so it should work fine.